Flutter v3.22 impeller render problem in one plus & some old version
when i am using Impeller and release the app
all other device is working fine except Oneplus nord n20 (physical device).
flutter doctor :
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.0, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64)
when using :
<meta-data
 android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.EnableImpeller"
 android:value="true"/>

whai i am seeing now in one plus nord 20:

what is my expected design :


Hi
Did you ever find a solution to this?
I am facing the same in a few devices...
